# Magento 2 How to get all active shipping methods via mysql?

Tags: magento2, database

I need to be able to query from mysql these fields

```
shipping_method_code
shipping_carrier_code
```

for a custom shipping method (ShipperHQ) I am trying to use from the REST Api.

Thanks

Comment: If I am assuming correctly, you need shipping method and carrier code for current quote, right?

Comment: Yes, correct... I don't really need this anymore, but if you have this easily, would be good to know for future, thanks!